# JSON:API FieldEnhancers - removing a resource object from a JSON:API response

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I need to remove a resource object (in this case a paragraph) from a JSON:API response when it matches a specific condition. I do not want to delete it, I just want to exclude the object from the response.

**Approach:**
I tried using a FieldEnhancer to access the resource object in "doUndoTransform()", check for the condition and skip/remove it before being displayed.

**Problem:**
So far I only succeeded in altering the data of my resource object. I'm able to manipulate its content but I haven't yet figured out how to exclude it from the output.

**Question:**
Is there any way or probably an alternative (to the FieldEnhancer approach) to achieve my goal? I thought about extending the schema in "getOutputJsonSchema()" but due to a lack of documentation I'm missing the possible options.

**Setup:**

Article (node) | List (paragraph) | Items | Item (paragraph containing my custom FieldGroup with criteria) (see below)

My FieldEnhancer is attached to *List* looping over each *Item* in *Items* to retrieve the entity ID and the condition. The custom FieldGroup which holds the condition can be attached to any entity so using a FieldEnhancer on a specific resource is also pretty fast.

**FieldEnhancer code example:**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function doUndoTransform($data, Context $context): mixed
{
    $entityId = $this->getEntityId($context);
    // if ok display object
    if ($this->fieldGroupProcessor->isCondition($entityId)) {
       return $data;
    }

    // else return null / skip / remove object
}

public function getOutputJsonSchema(): array
{
    return [
        'type' => 'object',
        'properties' => [],
    ];
}
```

JSON:API resource object example:

```
{
type: "paragraph--quicklinks",
id: "3eabd16d-92a5-468d-9968-ad7e24797340",
links: {
    self: {
        href: "http://127.0.0.1:8088/jsonapi/paragraph/quicklinks/3eabd16d-92a5-468d-9968-ad7e24797340"
    }
},
attributes: {
    heading: "Test"
},
relationships: {
    quicklinks_items: {
        data: [{
            type: "paragraph--quicklink_item",
            id: "af04ef25-bee5-401d-b5f7-1bf742349dde",
            meta: {
                target_revision_id: 230829,
                drupal_internal__target_id: 36089
            }
        },
        {
            type: "paragraph--quicklink_item",
            id: "0831315b-f6bd-46a4-87bf-feff5c9473bc",
            meta: {
                target_revision_id: 230831,
                drupal_internal__target_id: 36091
            }
        },
        {
            type: "paragraph--quicklink_item",
            id: "53b2a7d2-4388-4e5f-8681-a91cbe0e07c7",
            meta: {
                target_revision_id: 230833,
                drupal_internal__target_id: 36301
            }
        }],
        links: {
            related: {
                href: "http://127.0.0.1:8088/jsonapi/paragraph/quicklinks/3eabd16d-92a5-468d-9968-ad7e24797340/quicklinks_items"
            },
            self: {
                href: "http://127.0.0.1:8088/jsonapi/paragraph/quicklinks/3eabd16d-92a5-468d-9968-ad7e24797340/relationships/quicklinks_items"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

},